# How to make a loop for determining class KNN Method

Tags: java, loops, knn

i'm trying to create a program about KNN method and now I'm stuck in loop for determining the class. Here's my coding :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int titikx, titiky, k;
    int[] titikxl = new int[]{1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 6}; //first feature
    int[] titiky1 = new int[]{1, 3, 1, 5, 3, 2}; //second feature
    ArrayList<Double> nx = new ArrayList<Double>(), ny = new ArrayList<Double>(), 
    fn = new ArrayList<Double>(), arclass1 = new ArrayList<Double>(), 
    arclass2 = new ArrayList<Double>();

    //input hew data's features and k
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input first feature : ");
    titikx = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input second feature : ");
    titiky = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input k : ");
    k = input.nextInt();

    //count distance between new data and training data
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(i < titikxl.length || j <titiky1.length){
        nx.add(Math.pow(titikx - titikxl[i], 2));
        ny.add(Math.pow(titiky - titiky1[j], 2));
        i++;
        j++;
    }

    System.out.println(nx);
    System.out.println(ny);

    //convert arraylist to array
    Double[] nxarray = nx.toArray(new Double[nx.size()]);
    Double[] nyarray = ny.toArray(new Double[ny.size()]);

    //sum the array of distance first feature and second feature to get result

    int ii = 0, jj = 0;
    while (ii < nxarray.length || jj < nyarray.length){
        fn.add(Math.sqrt(nxarray[ii] + nyarray[jj]));
        ii++;
        jj++;
    }

    System.out.println(fn);
    Double[] fnarray = fn.toArray(new Double[fn.size()]);
    Double[] oldfnarray = fnarray; //array result before sort ascending

    //ascending array
    for(int id1 = 0; id1 < fnarray.length; id1++){
        for(int id2 = id1 + 1; id2 < fnarray.length; id2++){
            if(fnarray[id1]>fnarray[id2]){
                double temp = fnarray[id2];
                fnarray[id2] = fnarray[id1];
                fnarray[id1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int id = 0; id < fnarray.length; id++){
        System.out.print(fnarray[id] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    double[] classa = new double[]{oldfnarray[0], oldfnarray[1], oldfnarray[2]};
    double[] classb = new double[]{oldfnarray[3], oldfnarray[4], oldfnarray[5]};

    //determining what class the new data belongs
    for(int idb = 0; idb < classa.length; idb++){
        for(int idc = 0; idc < classb.length; idc++){
            for(int ida = 0; ida < fnarray.length; ida++){
                while(ida < k){
                    if (classa[idb] == fnarray[ida]){
                        arclass1.add(fnarray[ida]);
                    } 
                    if (classb[idc] == fnarray[ida]){
                        arclass2.add(fnarray[ida]);
                    }
                }    
            }
        }
    }

    if(arclass1.size() < arclass2.size()){
        System.out.println("The Class is B");
    } else{
        System.out.println("The Class is A");
    }
}
```

And the result is :

```
Input first feature : 2
Input second feature : 3
Input k : 3
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 4.0, 16.0] //distance feature x
[4.0, 0.0, 4.0, 4.0, 0.0, 1.0] //distance feature y
[2.23606797749979, 1.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 4.123105625617661] //result
1.0 2.0 2.0 2.23606797749979 2.23606797749979 4.123105625617661 //ascended result
//looping forever 
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 35 seconds)
```

As you can see, in the section determining class, when enter the loop the program seems doing the last loop forever. I try to modified it as capable as I could, yet still there's no result but error and running forever. Please help. Thank you most kindly.

Comment: `while(ida < k)` I don't see anything that ever changes the value of `ida`. I'm not sure if that's where your issue is, but it certainly looks suspicious.

Comment: oh yeah you right, I think because I'm too greedy using for and while simultaneously, so I delete for loop and only using while. But still forever loop. Thank you though for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the endless `while` loop - `ida`'s value never changes. I suggest modifying the entire code block because it is more complicated than it needs to be.

Before coming up with a solution, let's determine what we already know:

- the nearest `k`-neighbors (the sorted distances array, with indexes smaller than `k`)
- which neighbors belong to which class

It becomes obvious that in order to determine the class, we need to:

- check for every neighbor (outer loop) whether it is in class `A` (we need a first inner loop) or class `B` (we need second inner loop)
- if neighbor is found to be in class `A`, we increase counter for class `A`, otherwise we do that for class `B`
- compare counters: if counter for class `A` is greater, then the feature belongs in class `A`, otherwise in class `B`

To better understand what is going on, the *k-NN classification* algorithm is described comprehensively in [this tutorial](http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/KNN/KNN_Numerical-example.html).

**Code** (same structure as yours, though I renamed variables and simplified some parts for readability):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class KNN {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] feature1 = new int[] { 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 6 };
        int[] feature2 = new int[] { 1, 3, 1, 5, 3, 2 };

        //input hew data's features and k
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input first feature : ");
        int newFeature1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Input second feature : ");
        int newFeature2 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Input k : ");
        int k = input.nextInt();

        input.close();

        //count distance between new data and training data
        double[] distances1 = new double[feature1.length];
        double[] distances2 = new double[feature2.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < distances1.length; i++) {
            distances1[i] = Math.pow(newFeature1 - feature1[i], 2);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < distances2.length; i++) {
            distances2[i] = Math.pow(newFeature2 - feature2[i], 2);
        }

        System.out.println("Distance between first feature and first feature training data: " + Arrays.toString(distances1));
        System.out.println("Distance between second feature and second feature training data: " + Arrays.toString(distances2));

        //sum the array of distance first feature and second feature to get result
        double[] distanceSums = new double[distances1.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < distances1.length; i++) {
            distanceSums[i] = Math.sqrt(distances1[i] + distances2[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Distance sums: " + Arrays.toString(distanceSums));

        // sort array ascending
        double[] distanceSumsSorted = new double[distanceSums.length];
        System.arraycopy(distanceSums, 0, distanceSumsSorted, 0, distanceSums.length);
        Arrays.sort(distanceSumsSorted);

        System.out.println("Sorted distance sums: " + Arrays.toString(distanceSumsSorted));

        double[] classAMembers = new double[] { distanceSums[0], distanceSums[1], distanceSums[2] };
        double[] classBMembers = new double[] { distanceSums[3], distanceSums[4], distanceSums[5] };

        //determining what class the new data belongs
        int classACounts = 0;
        int classBCounts = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            // check if nearest neighbor belongs to class A
            for (int j = 0; j < classAMembers.length; j++) {
                if (distanceSumsSorted[i] == classAMembers[j]) {
                    classACounts++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // check if nearest neighbor belongs to class B
            for (int j = 0; j < classBMembers.length; j++) {
                if (distanceSumsSorted[i] == classBMembers[j]) {
                    classBCounts++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Class A members: " + Arrays.toString(classAMembers));
        System.out.println("Class B members: " + Arrays.toString(classBMembers));

        System.out.println("Counts for class A: " + classACounts);
        System.out.println("Counts for class B: " + classBCounts);

        if (classACounts < classBCounts){
            System.out.println("The Class is B.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The Class is A.");
        }
    }
}
```

For your example data the program outputs:

```
Input first feature : 2
Input second feature : 3
Input k : 3
Distance between first feature and first feature training data: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 4.0, 16.0]
Distance between second feature and second feature training data: [4.0, 0.0, 4.0, 4.0, 0.0, 1.0]
Distance sums: [2.23606797749979, 1.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 4.123105625617661]
Sorted distance sums: [1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 4.123105625617661]
Class A members: [2.23606797749979, 1.0, 2.23606797749979]
Class B members: [2.0, 2.0, 4.123105625617661]
Counts for class A: 1
Counts for class B: 2
The Class is B.
```

Comment: Wow, I realize my code is full of redundancies and far from perfect, so thanks for fix it. Appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem, it also made things easier to understand for me. :)